# How to delete/remove files from a pushed commit?

Tags: git

is it possible to delete/remove some unwanted files from remote and local repository?
I was a bit to fast and pushed 5 files to the remote repo. Now my colleague pushed his work and saw to late these unwanted files. So now there are 2 commits after my 'wrong' commit.

I tried to use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

and changed the first entry to "edit" and deleted that unwanted files.
Next I used

```
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

But GIT wont finalize it. It always said that I'm at the last commit and there is a rebase in progress. But I'm not able to continue to finish it.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily remove unwanted files from local git repositories:
Just remove them with
`git rm file`
or
`git rm -r directory` (if you add the `--cached`-flag the file doesn't get removed from your filesystem). Then commit (or commit --amend) to remove the file from the last commit (it stays in in the history, though).  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo)

If you want to remove it from  a remote repo follow the same steps and push afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't remove it from the git history.

Comment: I said so, I believe...

Answer (score -1):

```
git rm file
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
```